Tiktok link changing in when DOM loaded
I am creating a html site. The side nav bar has multiple linked images to social media sites. They all work, however when I am using an adblocker, the TikTok link gets removed when the adblocker sets the display property to none.
What I noticed is that TikTok links get replaced by a "https://tatrck.com/v1/go/--resofURL--" link which is what is being blocked. Is there anyway to get around this, so viewers of my site can actually see the TikTok link even when they are using an adblocker?

This is what I have in my html file
All the other links work fine, as they are not replaced when DOM is loaded
Image of my nav html

Image of developer window


Adblockers often target specific links and texts. Since the URL contains "tiktok.com," it is likely recognized as an advertisement and blocked.
To avoid this, create a shortlink for your TikTok profile and use that in the href link.(there are multiple services like https://bitly.com/ that can provide it for you free of charge)
Additionally, avoid using the word "tiktok" in the alt text or URL of the image tag to prevent it from being blocked.
